# Error in compiling ui dependency in android studio

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzahl.class

Comment: show me your dependency

Answer (score 0):

In terminal execute in root project folder:

```
./gradlew clean
```

Try this!

Comment: thanku for your answer but it is still showing error:* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug

BUILD FAILED

Comment: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0.
     Required by:
         ChatApplication:app:unspecified > com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) says that.

> Each version of FirebaseUI has dependency on a fixed version of these
>   libraries, defined as the variable firebase_version in
>   common/constants.gradle. If you are using any dependencies in your app
>   of the form compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-*:x.y.z' or compile
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services-*:x.y.z' **you need to make sure**
>   **that you use the same version that your chosen version of FirebaseUI**
>   **requires**.

[image]